# (Django 2.1)I can't serve static files while media files is bieng served perfectly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

The static files always give me a 404 error and I can't see why,I copied a style I've used before but not with this version of django.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
               ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I was using cdn and style tag for the whole time working on the project but now i want to wrap it up and use some css/js files already ready for me.

I tried collecting the static files by `python manage.py collectstatic` and it collected all the static files in the static folder but still doesn't load them and returns a 404 error

my dir:

```
/Eyelizer
    /App1
    /App2
    /Eyelizer
    /static
        /css
             /main1.css
    /Eyelizer
        /css
            /wanted.css
        /js
           /wanted.js
        /images
    /templates
    /media
```

Every kind of help is appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything like **`STATIC_DIR`** but it is **`STATICFILES_DIRS`**.

And also you have made a **typo mistake** in `STATIC_ROOT` while closing the bracket.

Just put the below in **`settings.py`** by removing all static related things.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: The `STATIC_ROOT` typo was here not in the settings and i guess that name the staticfiles dir to static files what made the problem,I will try it, Thanks!

Comment: @AMMARRADY, Just check if it works and let me know.